# How to add constraint to table in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I create a table

```
create table CARS{
    CAR_ID  NUMBER(10), CONSTRAINT X_CAR_ID NOT NULL
}
```

and now I want to change the name of the constraint, so I drop the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE CARS DROP CONSTRAINT X_CAR_ID;
```

This works correclty but, when I tried to add new constraint I have a problem,
my query:

```
ALTER TABLE CARS ADD CONSTRAINT XX_CAR_ID (CAR_ID) NOT NULL;
```

I thought that query, will be working correctly, but I get only error report:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904:
```

How to add correctly this constraint ?

Comment: @jarlh What do u mean ? 
Unfortunately, I do not understand you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost when it comes to Oracle constraints.

Comment: ANSI SQL answer: `ALTER TABLE CARS ADD CONSTRAINT XX_CAR_ID CHECK (CAR_ID IS NOT NULL)`.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you, but it create the same constraint but with other name  
?

Comment: Your syntax on the CREATE TABLE statement is wrong - there is no comma before the constraint definition, and { ... } should be ( ... ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I couldn't test it I believe the statement below is what you want:

```
ALTER TABLE CARS MODIFY CAR_ID CONSTRAINT XX_CAR_ID NOT NULL;
```

Oracle uses the `modify` keyword in this context.

To rename it without dropping first you would use:

```
alter table cars rename constraint x_car_id to xx_car_id;
```

See the [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2103997) for more info.

Comment: If I wanna modify just a name of constraint I can use yours query, without delete and add ? I understanding you correctly ? @jpw

Comment: The Oracle documentation requires parentheses (although perhaps it works without them as well):  `alter table cars modify (car_id constraint xx_car_id not null);`

Comment: @mathguy That may be the case; I'm no Oracle expert but I guess it did work without them as the OP said so :)